# How to use the apply method to check if data df["z"].iloc[i] == df["y"].iloc[i+1]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I tried to use

```
df["new_col"] = temp_df['y'].apply(lambda x: "True" if x == temp_df["z"].shift[-1] else "False")
```

However, I got the error "TypeError: 'method' object is not subscribable".

Desired output

```
z,y,new_col
3,4,True
4,5,False
6,7,True
7,8,False
```

Comment: you dont need apply, check with `series.shift()` to compare

Comment: There was a Typo...You are using `.shift[-1] ` instead of `.shift(-1)`

Comment: thanks for the help the correction above still resulted in the same error but I saw ankies reply and adjusted the code to use numpy.where instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["new_col"] = np.where(temp_df['y'].eq(temp_df["z"].shift(-1)), "True","False")
```

Works Correctly

Comment: Just use `df['new_col'] = df['y'] == df['z'].shift(-1)`  No need for the np.where here or if you need string dtype, `(df['y'] == df['z'].shift(-1)).astype(str)`